# Homestead Running, SSH Works, But HTTP Connections Time Out

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm having an issue with a homestead configuration that was previously running correctly. After reading some bad advice online regarding a separate issue, I accidentally wiped out my homestead.yaml by re-running init.bat, and have recreated the homestead config from memory the best I can. Most everything seems to be working - I can start the box successfully, and I can connect via SSH. My web root is mapped to the box correctly, as I can see all my project files on the box where I chose to map them. When I try to access the site via http (through the name I've mapped it to), I get a timeout. I've ensured that my hosts file has the update from myapp.app to 192.168.10.10, the same IP as in my homestead.yaml file. I will note, however, that when I ping 192.168.10.10 from the terminal, I also get a timeout.

Here's my Homestead.yaml:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:/Users/MyUsername/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/MyUsername/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:/Users/MyUsername/Projects/myapp_laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/code/myapp

sites:
    - map: myapp.app
      to: /home/vagrant/code/myapp/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

Here's my hosts file:

```
192.168.10.10 myapp.app
```

I'll also note that I can successfully access my app via: http://localhost:8000/
I have also restarted my host machine since updating the hosts file, and reprovisioned the box.

Comment: Maybe run a `netstat -n | find ":8000"` and try to find out what's running on your port 8000?

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the host machine again solved this for me.